# Is the android.text.Layout class connected with "layouts" (e.g. constraint layout) as generally known? What is it useful for?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have tried searching for helpful information on what the `android.text.Layout` class is and its application. I read the [documentation page here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/Layout) and it is not clear how it is used and in what context. I could not find any direct questions regarding this class on StackOverflow or elsewhere, and so far it I haven't found it covered in the course material that I am using.

The reason I am searching for it is because I want to know if it is something entirely different from "layouts" as generally known, such as `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc., which are classes derived from the `android.view.ViewGroup` base class.

I feel there is a cause for confusion here because `LinearLayout` etc. which is what we usually mean by the word "layout" are derived from a `ViewGroup` class, whereas the class actually named "Layout" seems to have nothing to do with layouts as commonly known and is derived from `java.lang.object` (or `kotlin.Any` in Kotlin)

In this context, I request clarification and perspectives regarding the `android.text.Layout` class and its use. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779934/how-is-staticlayout-used-in-android

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That link is partially helpful, but what I wanted to understand was if there was any connection (conceptually or from a code/design perspective) between the `android.text.Layout` and the "layouts" which are view groups used for organizing other views. Can I conclude the two are entirely unrelated?

Comment: `android.text.Layout` is an `abstract` class and `StaticLayout`, `DynamicLayout` and `BoringLayout` extend it. They are not related to the `ViewGroup`s as `LinearLayout`,`FrameLayout`....

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for confirming that the two are not related.