# How to set Padding for text in StaticLayout Android?

Tags: android, text, staticlayout, sticker

I want to set padding for text created using `StaticLayout` in Android

[image]

I can't set padding for text and text is cut off when using font and using alignment

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3WKn.png)

Comment: Can you please add your code to your post

Comment: use  android:gravity="center"

Comment: Maybe here is answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779935/3815660

Comment: @DhruvSakariya i want to add in code

Comment: @Yurii I did that but when I use the font, it cuts off the text at both ends

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I created text like this, but when using the font, the text is cut off at both ends https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779934/how-is-staticlayout-used-in-android/41779935#41779935